# python importing level 2 packages

Tags: python, git, import, git-submodules

I have added a git submodule in my project. Now all the imports in that submodule are broken because I have to use the full path of import. 
For example, if the structure is like this:

Myproject:
- submodule_project:
-- package1:
--- code1.py
-- package2:
--- code2.py

Now, in code1.py there is `from package2 import code2`. It tells me that package2 is unresolved reference. It is only resolved if I change it to `from submodule_project.package2 import code2`.
I don't want this because I don't want to change anything in the submodule. I just added it to use some of its packages in my project and to get regularly updated whenever its developers update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `package2` to be a top-level importable package its parent directory (`submodule_project` in your case) has to be in `sys.path`. There are many way to do it: `sys.path.append()`, `sys.path.insert()`, `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Or may be you don't want to have the code as a submodule at all. It doesn't make sense to have a submodule if the code in the submodule uses absolute import instead of relative (`from ..package2 import code2`). May be the package should be installed in `site-packages` (global or in a virtual environment) but not attached to the project as a submodule.